# Why is my C# RabbitMQ consumer integration test failing? The queue is not empty when I expect it to be

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, integration-testing, xunit

I'm trying to integration test some RabbitMQ code. Right now, I have a class `RabbitMqConsumer` with a `BeginConsuming()` method that looks like this:

```
    public void BeginConsuming()
    {
        var messageConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(ConsumerChannel);

        //Consumes messages from queue
        messageConsumer.Received += (model, eventArgs) =>
        {
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Body);
            HandleMessage(message);

            // Send a message to the stats service to recalculate the stats when each game ends
            if (GameplayMessageHandler.GetMessageType(message) == "gameEnd")
            {
                var jsonMsgObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message);
                var gameGuid = (Guid) jsonMsgObject["game_guid"];
                SendPostGameStatsEventToStatsService(gameGuid);
            }

            // After *everything* is done for processing this message, fire the message handled event
            MessageHandled?.Invoke();
        };

        ConsumerChannel.BasicConsume(
            queue: _rabbitSettings.GamesQueueName,
            autoAck: true,
            consumer: messageConsumer);

        Log.Logger.Information("Now consuming RabbitMq messages in channel: {queueName}", _rabbitSettings.GamesQueueName);
    }
```

I've declared the following event/delgate in the class:

```
public delegate void OnMessageHandledListener();
public event OnMessageHandledListener MessageHandled;
```

The idea is to fire this event when RabbitMQ is done processing each message. Then, I can write a test that looks like this:

```
model.BasicPublish("", "GameEvents", false, null, msgBytes);

Assert.True(fakeRabbitServer.Queues["GameEvents"].Messages.Count.Equals(1));
gameEventsRabbitConsumer.MessageHandled += () =>
{
 Assert.True(fakeRabbitServer.Queues["GameEvents"].Messages.Count.Equals(0));
};
gameEventsRabbitConsumer.BeginConsuming();
```

However, this test fails on the line `Assert.True(fakeRabbitServer.Queues["GameEvents"].Messages.Count.Equals(0));`

Why is my queue not getting emptied at this point? Is this in error in how I am handling the async nature of things? How can I correct this?